# How to synchronously illuminate four LED lights with analogWrite

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm using Arduino Uno and want to light four LEDs synchronously using the analogwrite method, but they are illuminating sequentially instead. Here is my code:

```
int brightness = 0;    
int fadeAmount = 5;    
boolean first = true;

void setup()  { 
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
} 
void loop()  {

  if (first) {
    // these should iluminate synchronously
    analogWrite(2, brightness);
    analogWrite(3, brightness);
    analogWrite(4, brightness);
    analogWrite(5, brightness);
  } else {
    // these should iluminate synchronously
    analogWrite(6, brightness);
    analogWrite(7, brightness);
    analogWrite(8, brightness);
    analogWrite(9, brightness);
  }

  brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

  if (brightness == 0 || brightness == 255) {
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount ;
    if (brightness == 0) {
      reverseFirst();
    }
  }           

  delay(5);                            
}

void reverseFirst(){
  if (first) {
    first = false;
  } else {
    first = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say they are illuminating sequentially? How far apart? Also, reduce your code to a MWE, and it will help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Connect all LEDs that should light up together to one pin?

Comment: they illuminate one after the other. I want them to come off and fade at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

analogWrite only effectively works on pins 3,5,6,9,10,11 because they are the PWM pins. According to the analogWrite source code all other pins if used with analogWrite, will default back to digitalWrite.

So I suspect you will not be able to do proper analog control on the other pins and that might be why not all of them are switching on at the same time.

If brightness is important to you then I propose that you only use the true PWM pins. If you require more than the six pins then there are analog expander chips which you can acquire or more simpler you can have a look at something like "ShiftPWM". It is a library which uses a shift register to shift pulses to its outputs effectively allowing you to control brightness of LEDs. Keep in mind that it is no longer being maintained.

Comment: Thanks. I actually need 8 leds.